# Two divs are overlapping and how to get auto height for a div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs like:

```
<header id="header">
  <div>Hello Vai</div>
</header>

<div id="banner">
 <div><img src="http://www.encodedna.com/images/theme/easy-image-resizer.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 10;
}

#banner {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

See carefully while I fixed the upper div, image div will get close to upper div.
I don't want to fixed any div height. They will get auto height with their inner divs. And two divs will come one after another.

I didn't  get any solution!! But I saw a lot of questions about it.

Comment: Can you clarify for us what you are trying to accomplish? divs are block level elements - that means by default they should take up all horizontal space and should take the height of any fixed-height children...

Comment: I don't want to fixed any div's height. They will calculate automatically their height (I don't know how to calculate without JS) and two divs will display one after another.

Comment: Right - so if I understand correctly the divs should behave that way by default. Is this what you are trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/8a5du53d/

Comment: Actually it's a long code so I didn't share. I am trying to clarify it more.

Comment: Sure - if you can do that I will try to help because if you are not wanting the result I posted in the code sample then it is not clear to me what you are trying to do

Comment: I have edited my code. You can see now. Actually upper div is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: If you apply `position:fixed` to a `div`, it would by default overlap other `div`s. That is how `position:fixed` works. The only way you can get rid of this is apply a `padding-top` to the `body` element just equal to the height of your `#header`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    z-index: 10;
}

#banner {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

In the code that you shared, remove position fixed to achieve the desired behaviour.

```
Position: fixed
```

Will overlap with other divs however if u really want to use it, specify it inside a div and then apply top:inherit in order to shift down the lower div.